# Non-isomorphic groups such that there are epis from one to another

Tags: gr.group-theory

Are there (infinite) non-isomorphic groups $G, H$ such that there are surjective group homomorphisms $f: G\to H$ and $g: H\to G$?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119255/almost-isomorphic-groups

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate (in fact a very special case) of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119255/almost-isomorphic-groups
as Stefan Kohl points out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, an example is $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This even works in the category of rings.

Comment: I hope that the word "even" is not confusing: The rings also surject onto each other, hence also the underlying abelian groups, but that they are not isomorphic as rings does not necessarily imply that they are not isomorphic as abelian groups.

Comment: Bonus question: Is there an example with finitely generated $k$-algebras?

Answer (score 8):

The first example that comes to mind, $G=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q}$ and $H=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q}$, seems to work.

FYI, a related example $G=\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty\mathbb{Q}$ handles your question with "surjective" replaced by "injective".

Comment: For the question with "injective" instead of "surjective", it sufficies to remember that the free group with $2$ generators contains the free group with $3$ generators as a subgroup.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: sure, that's another good example. I just like the fact that this pair of questions allows for almost identical examples.