# Can a simple group be equivalent to a non-simple group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Two abstract groups $G$ and $H$ are called equivalent, $G\sim H$, if each of them is isomorphic to a subgroup of another.

**Question:** Can a simple group $G$ be equivalent to a non-simple group $H$?

Of course, we are talking about infinite groups here. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's easy, the group $A$ of finitely supported even permutations of the integers and $A\times F$ for any nontrivial finite group.

Comment: (I didn't post as an answer because I rather answer in comments off-topic questions)

Comment: @YCor I think you are being too strict here in considering it off-topic. The vast majority of questions on math.stackexchange are much more elementary than this, and so that site is becoming less and less suitable for questions at this level (although it is true that someone would probably have answered it there).

Comment: It is rarely reasonable to ask a question from your narrow specialty, because you probably know it better than others. On the other hand, whatever you ask beyond your specialty is most probably going to be elementary for experts in that subject. Does this mean you should always ask questions only on SE? I don't think so.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm aware that most questions in MathSE are much more elementary than this. I'm also aware that such a question would have quickly been answered on MathSE.

Comment: By definition, "MathOverflow is a question and answer site for professional mathematicians". I am one, so I feel free to ask questions to my colleagues if I feel it would take me unreasonably long time to find the answer by myself. Note that there is nothing in the definition regarding "asking vs answering" statistics and other religious beliefs. Half of the questions I asked on SE remained unanswered, and many of them are not even viewed sufficiently many times. So I need repost them on MO after losing a few days in vain.

Comment: This said, I do choose ME when I feel the question must be textbook standard. This time I didn't feel like that for some reason.

Comment: In practice, MO has never been for technically for professional mathematicians.  Questions from non-professional mathematicians are welcome when they have are of research level, while too elementary, unclear, or too broad questions of professionals are often closed or migrated too. And many users act anonymously and are not classified so. Thus, I think this sentence is a rough approximation of the target, also in order to discourage people with no relation to research to post highly off-topic questions here, but is certainly not here to select qualified users among others.

Comment: For a related question, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119255/almost-isomorphic-groups.

Comment: I think this is *exactly* the kind of question MO was set up for, and I am very dismayed by the votes to close. Or are we just now in the business of saying "let them eat brioche"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. (This is corrected and expanded since the first version.) There are easy examples of simple groups $G$ such that $G\times G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$. One example is the group of finitely supported even permutations of a countable infinite set. Another is the quotient of all permutations of a countably infinite set by the finitely supported ones. Another is the infinite special linear group (direct limit of $SL_n(k)$) of a field.